# What app to download Torrents or how to start mTorrent

Tags: 12.10, downloads, utorrent

I have downloaded mTorrent for Linux 64bit but I don't know what to run to install it. How do I run it or is there any other way to download torrents?

Comment: what distro are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try transmission. It's installed in 12.10